# Play `wma` files without installing whole Media Feature Pack in Windows x N

Tags: windows, audio, codec, wma

I have Windows 8.1 Pro N version installed, which comes without Windows Media Player and 'media features'. This includes no support for `*.wma` files. I have been looking for a way to install codec for `wma` files, but all I found is to install whiole [Windows Media Feature Pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2929699), which is not what I expected when I was installing N version.

The only codecs available on Microsoft downloads webpages are [for windows xp and lower](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6220).

I have already installed K-Lite Codeck Pack (Basic), wma still doesn't work.

Is there any way to play `wma` files on Windows N without installing whole Media Feature Pack?

Answer (score 0):

You could download and install just the [Windows Media Player](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-media-player), as it is free.

You could download and use a third party player like [Foobar](http://www.foobar2000.org/) which would allow you to play virtually any common lossy or lossless audio format. And is also free.

Have you also gone in and checked your file associations to determine if the file format is non-associated with a program that could play it?

Steps:

1. Search Windows for 'file associations'
2. Click the choice that says 'Change the file type associated with a file extension' or similar
3. Find your file type
4. Click 'Change programs...'
5. Determine if there are any media players on your computer that are actually capable of playing the file format. Usually very visible.

Edit:

Per a discussion on the [Foobar Forums](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=102693&hl=wma), in order for Foobar to play .wma files, it does so by accessing the windows API (Application Programming Interface). If WMP or the Windows Media Format Runtime isn't installed, then it doesn't have the means to translate the file format. This is a contradiction of the Foobar [Wiki](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Foobar2000), under supported formats, which says it can play .wma natively.

A workaround is the option of trying to install an older version of the WMP software by using Compatibility Mode to install it in Windows 8.1. This would provide the media formats for Foobar to reference, without having to install all of the extraneous material from the Windows Media Feature Pack.

Other options would be using other media players like Media Player Classic, which wasyl has already found will support the format.

Also, as suggested by Ramhound, using the media player VLC.

Comment: My point was to *not install* WMP - it bundles with lots of stuff I don't want ([download webpage](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/download-windows-media-player) instructs to install Media Feature Pack I mentioned before). I don't want neither WMP nor "Media sharing and Play To", ActiveX controls or anything. I just want WMA codecs.

Comment: But I have now opened wma file in Media Player Classic (I swapped K-Lite Basic for Standard) and it does play! While foobar/aimp don't recognize it (foobar console states that "WMA support requires Windows Media runtime libraries installed"). I was under impression that no program is able to play it. So now to enable wma in foobar...

Comment: Apologies for the WMP. I don't use it and was still under the impression that Microsoft still let you download just the program.

Comment: @wasyl There are two possibilities that I can think of for Foobar. 1. See if you can install an older version of WMP with just the player that doesn't have all of the extra garbage. Then you can use Foobar to convert the files. 2. See if installing just the codecs for Windows Media Codecs from the following works: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=507.

Comment: Unfortunately previous versions of WMP as well as codecs from link you provided are for windows xp/vista/etc and refuse to install on Windows 8.1

Comment: @wasyl - Why can't you use something like VLC which will support virtually any codec.  You can always upgrade to a license of Windows 8 that allows WMP player to be installed.

Comment: @Ramhound I enjoy foobar and so I want to use it. I also believe it's os' fault I can't play WMA files, as only mpc plays them through its own decoders. Also the point is I *do not want* windows media player. It comes with too much garbage

Comment: @wasyl - Are we talking about the same product. The WMP only comes with codecs and a video player.  This really sounds like you simply don't have the correct codec install to play the file which is the reason I suggested VLC.

Comment: @Ramhound - from WMP page: "for Windows 8.1 N and KN editions, get the Media Feature Pack.", [Media Feature Pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2703761): WMP, ActiveX control,a/v codecs, digital rights management, windows media device manager, media sharing, windows portable devices infrastructure,Calendar,Mail,Messaging,People,and I didn't list everything. All I want is a/v codecs

Comment: @wasyl - Alright.  I don't even notice those features since I already disabled them manually.  If the codec pack you installed does not provide the codec you need to use the software you want, you either need to find a different codec pack or use a different video player like VLC.

Comment: @wasyl Have you tried installing an earlier version of WMP using Compatability Mode? Instructions can be found here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows

Comment: @wasyl: It sounds like you are able to play WMA via MPC using non system decoders. Doesn't that solve your problem? Why do you need the ability to install just the WMA decoders without the rest of the media pack?